# How to make sequence range for the time period

Tags: r

I am having a Time period as Tenure and I need to split on range basis by using sequence.

```
DF

Tenure

3y 11m 30d 0H 0M 0S
7y 3m 30d 0H 0M 0S
6y 5m 30d 0H 0M 0S
8y 11m 30d 0H 0M 0S
7y 11m 30d 0H 0M 0S
```

I need to convert above as range by using `seq(3,9,by=1.5)`

```
Tenure
(3,4.5]
(6,7.5]
(6,7.5]
(7.5,9]
(7.5,9]
```

I have used the code below in R. It is working but some how showing the wrong info, some are giving as NA as well, which is strange to me.

```
DF$Tenure<-cut(DF$Tenure@year,breaks=seq(3,9,by=1.5),right=TRUE)
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to ask question, please post your samples as text in your post in CODE TAGS button.

Comment: Please edit your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)  for details. Thank you.

Comment: While iam editing my post in text box,it is shwoing error saying that my post is not in code area formatted by four spaces,hence i ahve attached the image for this time.Can someone suggest why iam facing the problem why editing the question

Comment: One solution would be to add four spaces in front of your code. Alternatively, you could select the relevant code snippet and click on the `{}` symbol.

Comment: Short cut select your code and press `ctrl K` key

Comment: [Learn how to format your code appropriately here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first think of converting `Tenure` to `period/duration` in `years`. Once `Tenure` is in years one can apply `cut` to create factors.

An option using `lubridate` can be as:

```
library(lubridate)

df$Tenure <- cut(as.numeric(period(df$Tenure),unit="years"), seq(3,9,by=1.5))

df
#    Tenure
# 1 (3,4.5]
# 2 (6,7.5]
# 3 (6,7.5]
# 4 (7.5,9]
# 5 (7.5,9]
```

**Note:**

`as.numeric(period(df$Tenure),unit="years")` converts data from `3y 11m 30d 0H 0M 0S` format to absolute numeric years (e.g. `3.998802` years) format.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Tenure
'3y 11m 30d 0H 0M 0S'
'7y 3m 30d 0H 0M 0S'
'6y 5m 30d 0H 0M 0S'
'8y 11m 30d 0H 0M 0S'
'7y 11m 30d 0H 0M 0S'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```